# Get the same field twice with different values in the same row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Considering these 2 tables:

Table **orders**:

```
    order_id owner_id client_id
    ---------------------------
    123      2        1
    124      1        2
```

Table **users**

```
    user_id name
    ------------
    1       Bill
    2       John
```

I'm trying to get the following result:

```
    order_id owner_name client_name
    -------------------------------
    123      John       Bill
    124      Bill       John
```

What is the "best" query?

Thanks!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select o.order_id, 
       ow.name as owner_name, 
       cl.name as client_name
from orders o
  join users ow on o.owner_id = ow.user_id
  join users cl on o.client_id = cl.user_id
```

Answer (score 2):

`JOIN` the table `Users` twice:

```
SELECT
  o.order_id,
  ow.name 'owner_name',
  cl.name 'client_name'
FROM Orders o
INNER JOIN users ow ON o.owner_id = ow.user_id
INNER JOIN users cl ON o.client_id = cl.user_id
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73e83/2)

Answer (score 0):

Using CROSS APPLYs -

```
    DECLARE @Orders TABLE(Order_Id INT,Owner_Id INT,Client_Id INT)
    INSERT INTO @Orders
    SELECT 123,2,1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 124,1,2

    SELECT * FROM @Orders;

    DECLARE @Users TABLE(UserId INT,Name VARCHAR(10))
    INSERT INTO @Users
    SELECT 1,'Bill' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'John'

    SELECT * FROM @Users;

    SELECT b.Order_Id
          ,a.Name AS Owner_Name
          ,c.Name AS Client_Name 
    FROM @Orders b
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM @Users) a
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM @Users) c
    WHERE a.UserId=b.Owner_Id
        AND c.UserId=b.Client_Id
    ORDER BY b.Order_Id
```